# WatchKit how to check current state of WKInterfaceSwitch

Tags: ios, watchkit

Im trying to figure out if my instance of WKInterfaceSwitch is currently in on or off position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that. You need to track with a variable the status of the `WKInterfaceSwitch` in your code.

Let's say your default value for a `WKInterfaceSwitch` is false.

In your `awakeWithContext`: method do this:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    self.switchStatus = NO;
}
```

In Objective-C you would declare a property with a BOOL value.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL switchStatus;
```

Then create an action from your Switch object to your header file.

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(BOOL)value;
```

And in the implementation file write.

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(BOOL)value {
     self.switchStatus = value;
}
```

You are now able to check the status of your Switch by just using `self.switchStatus` for example like this:

```
    NSLog(@"Switch is now: %@", self.switchStatus ? @"true" : @"false");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sure there's a good reason for not being able to do `switch.isOn`. I'd love to know what it is!